# Progressive web application - not honouring screen orientation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, manifest, progressive-web-apps

My web app is not honouring the orientation set in my `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1",
  "name": "My App",
  "short_name": "My App",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "img/myapp/launcher-icon-0-75x.png",
      "sizes": "36x36",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/myapp/launcher-icon-1x.png",
      "sizes": "48x48",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/myapp/launcher-icon-1-5x.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/myapp/launcher-icon-2x.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/myapp/launcher-icon-3x.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/myapp/launcher-icon-4x.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "theme_color": "#43c1b1",
  "background_color": "#43c1b1",
  "start_url": "/myapp",
  "scope": "/myapp",
  "orientation": "landscape",
  "display": "standalone"

}
```

Everything else works - the icons and the background colour so why would there be a problem forcing landscape?

Chrome (on mobile) v 57.0.2987

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original manifest.json is correct but it only works on Chrome Canary (version 59) but not on Chrome Stable (version 57).

I was unable to find any mention of it in the release logs though.

Comment: Google recently announced [what was new in Chrome 58](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/nic58), expect details about 59 in six weeks.

Comment: Doesn't work in 2020 in Chrome for Android version 83

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing it right. Based on this [page](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/#specify_the_initial_orientation_of_the_page), you can enforce a specific orientation, which is advantageous for apps that work in only one orientation by using this `"orientation": "landscape"`.

Try to place first the display before the orientation like in this [example](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-installable-web-apps-with-webapp-manifest-in-chrome-38-for-Android#creating_the_manifest).

```
{
  "short_name": "Kinlan's Amaze App",
  "name": "Kinlan's Amazing Application ++",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-2x.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-3x.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-4x.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "landscape"
}
```

Comment: Seems that changing the order of display and orientation didn't work either. :)