# Orientation property of manifest.json is not working

Tags: progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

This is my manifest.json

```js
{
  "name": "XXXXX",
  "short_name": "XXXXX",
  "start_url": "/",
  "gcm_sender_id": "XXX",
  "background_color": "#dfdfdf",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "landscape",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "\/icons\/android-chrome-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image\/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "\/icons\/android-chrome-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image\/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "\/icons\/android-chrome-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image\/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "\/icons\/android-chrome-256x256.png",
      "sizes": "256x256",
      "type": "image\/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

This web app should always be in landscape mode, but it opens in portrait mode.

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494388/progressive-web-application-not-honouring-screen-orientation) present here with the same problem, but none of the answers are solving my problem

Comment: What happens if yo uset your start_url to "start_url": "/index.html" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494388/progressive-web-application-not-honouring-screen-orientation/43511606#43511606

Comment: @noogui i tried your suggestion but that didn't work either. My web app still opens in portrait mode :(

Comment: @KevinFarrugia yeah problem is same, but i haven't find any solution.

Comment: @yash kochar what chrome version? Have you been able to replicate on canary?

Comment: Chrome version 58.0.3029.83. I haven't tried it on canary because end users will use only chrome, so i have to fix on chrome only. 
It was working fine before April but after April i am having the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Progressive web application - not honouring screen orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494388/progressive-web-application-not-honouring-screen-orientation)

Comment: paste your manifest

Answer (score 0):

I just tried `"orientation": "landscape"` on a [sample app](https://basic-pwa-landscape.glitch.me/), and it seems to work correctly. You can see the code for the sample [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/basic-pwa-landscape?path=manifest.json%3A15%3A2)

Based on your description, there are two possibilities why this may have failed at the time. First, it may have been a bug in Chrome that prevented this from happening. And second, the escaping of the forward slashes in your `icons` properties of your manifest may have caused issues parsing the manifest.

For example, you icons property should be:

```json
"orientation": "landscape",
"icons": [
  {
    "src": "/icons/android-chrome-128x128.png",
    "sizes": "128x128",
    "type": "image/png"
  },
  {
    "src": "/icons/android-chrome-144x144.png",
    "sizes": "144x144",
    "type": "image/png"
  },
  {
    "src": "/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
    "sizes": "192x192",
    "type": "image/png"
  },
  {
    "src": "/icons/android-chrome-256x256.png",
    "sizes": "256x256",
    "type": "image/png"
  }
]
```

Comment: I noticed that app, when you go to the menu in Chrome Mobile, gives you the option to install it... my app only gives you the option to "Add to Home screen". Should that make any difference? My manifest doesn't have icon, color, shortcut or share target tags, but i don't see why i should need them just for landscape mode to work

Comment: Ok this is weird.  I  updated from Chrome 87 to 89 and re-added to the home page and now it shows landscape but i still can't get rid of the huge title bar at the top, even though i'm using display:standalone